# Change Cursor when hovering over url RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Currently when hovering over a url/link in a RichTextBox (WinForms) the cursor changes to a really low quality cursor without anti aliasing. I would like to use the default windows one, which looks way better, but I couldn't find any solutions... I only found a way to change the general hover cursor, but not when hovering over urls.
Thanks for all replies :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the cursor you're seeing and what you want it to be?

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mouse-cursor-hand-pointer.svg looks similar to  the right image, but I want to it look like the "aero_link.cur" in "C:\Windows\Cursors". Sadly cant take a windows screenshot where you can see the cursor

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug between RichTextBox and HiDPI support. The control properly renders text in HiDPI when HiDPI mode is enabled in the WinForms application, but it doesn't have the updated cursor.

Depending on the use case, you might consider using the WebBrowser control or something similar. It appears to support the higher resolution pointer cursor. It would work pretty well for viewing content, but for editing content, it might get a bit rough.

As a gross, hacky workaround, you might be able to add MouseMove event handlers to detect if the mouse is over a hyperlink or not and change the cursor for the whole control manually. This would involve the GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point) method passing in the Point from the MouseMove event args, then looking at the RTF Codes in the string from the Rtf property. If the CharIndex is the non-RTF string, you'd need to use the Text property, then determine if there's a URL there using some sort of Regex.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly do I detect if the mouse is over a hyperlink? I couldn't find solutions to doing this anywhere.

Comment: I updated with a few technical hints at the hacky workaround.